# Is it possible sending big size files by socket in blob format js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I try to send by socket files

```
   <input className="form-control" type="file" id="dropPhotoForm" onChange={selectFile} multiple/>

    const selectFile = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const messageObject = {
            body: file,
            type: file.type,
            filename: file.name
        }
        
        setPhotos([messageObject])
    }

    function dropPhotoHandler() {
        socket.emit("dropPhoto", photos, serverId);
    }
```

and save files on server side:

```
import {saveAs} from "file-saver";

 socketRef.current.on("incomingPhoto", (files, incomingServerId) => {
            if (files && incomingServerId === currentClientIdRef.current) {
                     saveAs(new Blob([file.body], {type: file.type}), file.filename);
            }
        });
```

Files with small size sends good, but with big size 3mb and hire doesn't send.
There is no any errors in console, I just wait for a long time and that all.